# Android 7.0 Toggle Airplane Mode Programatically

Tags: android

I have tried all solutions already provided on StackOverflow but they are all quite old and no one seem to have tried it for nougat. I am making a utility tool which allows a user to toggle airplane mode on nougat, Someone please share a way to do that programatically. Also I have not been able to find any help regarding notification pull down programatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can't toggle airplane mode programatically. Check the [Official Android 4.2 API Documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Also tried all the older suggestions, the only thing i have in mind is to open the airplane mode screen with :

```
Intent airPlaneModeIntent = new        Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(airPlaneModeIntent);
```

and then use adb commands to tap on the radio button with the on/off setting.